# A simple join consumes too much memory - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, out-of-memory

I have this join :

```
var andlist = (from cust in custFinal
               join serv in db.Service on cust.ID equals serv.CustID
               select new JoinObj
               {
                   Name = cust.name,
                   ServiceID = serv.ID,
               });
```

`custFinal` is a list of `Customer`s that contains only one object. db.Service is a DbSet and there are only four rows whose `custID` equals customer object's `ID` in `Service` table. When I use `ToList()` or `Count()`, used memory quickly exceeds 1GB and I'm getting outOfMemory exception. Can you tell me what is wrong with this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of entity framework is that? EF Core?

Comment: @Evk it is 6.1.3

Comment: how many rows of data are there

Comment: @LeiYang in Service table there are about 1.1M rows.

Comment: @LeiYang in custFinal there is only one object. I mean list count is 1

Comment: And joining 1 million rows is simple for you?

Comment: can you replace join with simple temp lists sub queries(maybe for performance comparison)? eg: `int id = xxx ;  var objService = from Sevice where...ID == id;`

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't know that I shouldn't use joins when the db tables are a little big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you don't really perform join on server. `custFinal` as you said is just in-memory list, not a database table or query. So it is `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`. When you perform a join - it calls `IEnumerable.Join`, not `IQueryable.Join` method. The latter would build a query but the former will just pull all arguments into memory and perform join in-memory. So in result - whole `Service` table in pulled into memory and joined there (easy to check if you log EF context queries - you will see that it just performs select all from Service query).

If you change the order of arguments in a join so that `IQueryable.Join` would be executed - that won't help either, because you cannot join database table with in-memory list with Entity Framework anyway. So you have to find another way, for example:

```
var ids = custFinal.Select(c => c.ID).ToArray();
var matchingServices = db.Service.Where(serv => ids.Contains(serv.CustID)).Select(c => new {c.ServiceID, c.CustID}).ToArray();
// now filter `custFinal` based on `matchingServices`, in memory.
```

That will perform `CustID IN (...)` query instead of a join. If you insist on having a join - you will have to do that with raw sql, without entity framework (you will also need to create custom table type in sql server, if you use SQL server).

Comment: Is there a way to convert `List` to `IEnumerable` back? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. `List` is already `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I mean if I use `custFinal` as an `IEnumerable`, it works, so is there a way for conversion?

Comment: If `custFinal` is `List<Customer>` - it's already IEnumerable. You can just cast it if you want: `(IEnumerable<Customer>) custFinal` (not sure why do that though).

Comment: IEnumerable is the base interface for all non-generic collections that can be enumerated.  IEnumerable contains a single method, GetEnumerator, which returns an IEnumerator. So if your code works with it, it should work with Lists. If not, there is probably something else wrong in the sequence.